# Network discovery and accounts other than Public

Tags: windows-7, networking, network-shares, home-networking

According to the Windows 7 help page entitled "What is network discovery?", it "affects whether your computer can find other computers and devices on the network and whether other computers on the network can find your computer."  Nowhere does it say that it is only for the "Public" account.  To turn on network discovery, it says to:

1. [Go] to open Advanced sharing settings.
2. Click the chevron to expand the current network profile.
3. Click Turn on network discovery, and then click Save changes.

I'm confused by the fact that, even though I'm logged in with a specific (non-administator) user account, I only see two entries ["Home or Work" and "Public (current profile)"] and only second one seems to be a "current profile" as specified by step#2 above.  Both have chevrons, but only the latter has a radio buttons to "Turn on network discovery". Does this mean that microsoft's terminology "network discovery", and whatever functionality is encompassed by that term, only applies to the Public folder?

Comment: You are confused about the "Public account." The account you are logged in with has *nothing* to do with whether Network Discovery is enabled or which Network Profile (Home/Work or Public) is active. Please clarify what's promoting you to ask about *user accounts* in this question.

Comment: I'm asking about Public as an account because the Public folder shows up in the c:\Users folder.  Because of that, it seems to be an account, though I have to admit, I'm not entirely sure.  If it isn't, I think it would be helpful to provide that information as part of an answer.  It would also be helpful if you elaborated on what you meant by the account having nothing to do with Network discovery. You've said a lot about what I got wrong, but an explanation of how things actually work would be very  helpful and appreciated.

Comment: I think this dicussion is getting mired down on a detail. After some searching, it was clear to me that, even though a user folder structure is imposed within the Public folder, there is no specific user associated with it (even though it resides in the User folder).  Be that as it may, I'm still interested in whether how to interpret the help text that I quoted.  That's the main reason I posted.  Thanks.

Comment: "even though it resides in the User folder" - Nop, it isn't. It leaving in dedicated folder `C:\Users\Public` with its own Documents, Downloads... It is just projected to any logged in user's account and can be used to share data between user's accounts. When network discovery is turned on, then `C:\Users\Public` would be available on network if you enable to share this Public account in `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Network and Sharing Center\Advanced sharing settings`.

Comment: "Does this mean that microsoft's terminology "network discovery", and whatever functionality is encompassed by that term, only applies to the Public folder?" - No. Basically "network discovery" simply either enable firewall to block local resources(Public profile) or it open ports in firewall that allows windows share (to be discovered by others) as well enable scanning network for master browser who holding list of other computers (Private/Work profile).

Comment: We seem to be in violent agreement about where the `Public` folder
resides -- in `c:\Users`.  My point was that this can cause people to
think of it as a user account's folder tree.  Indeed, the subfolders
largely mirror the subfolders of an actual user account. As I found,
however, no user/account owns that folder, though access can be given
to the actual user accounts.

Comment: My confusion about sharing being restricted to Public is clearing up.
The Public *profile* is a concept that is independent of Public *folder*,
which I thought was owned by a Public account.  Instead, the Public
profile is a category of network connection.  However, inside each
network profile (including the Public profile, but also others), I can
enable sharing of the contents of the Public folder tree.

Comment: Based on Twisty Impersonator's comment, I'm guessing that the sharing
options in each network profile applies to the whole computer, across
all accounts.  That is, those switches are not specific to the account
that I'm logged into, even though some switches apply explicitly and
specifically to the Public folder.  If anyone wishes to summarize this
into an answer, please do.  Otherwise, I'll do it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only confusion that you found, it is word `Public` that used in two different concepts of user's accounts and network profiles that in fact are different animals.

`Public` folder lives in dedicated location `C:\Users\Public` with its own Documents, Downloads... It is just projected to any logged in user's account and can be used to share data between ANY user's accounts since it has READ/WRITE permissions for all authorized users on common folders "Documents, Downloads, Music, Video, Images". This folder also containing restricted(read only permissions for non administrator users) folders such as "Desktop" that holds icons/shortcuts available for all users.
When one opening windows explorer, content of `Public` folder displayed in `Libraries` (When you click for example on `Libraries->Documents` you will see 2 folders, - one `My Documents` that is private and available by default to only logged in user and another one `Public Documents` that is shareable with all users on particular computer. In fact, actual location of `My Documents` is in `C:\Users\AccountName\Documents` and location of `Public Documents` is in the:
`C:\Users\Public\Documents`)
Logged in user has direct access to both locations and need to keep in mind purpose of "Public Documents" which is shared folder available to all users on given computer.

Regarding network profiles(*Private/Work, Public*):
For a given network profile, if "network discovery" is turned on, then `C:\Users\Public` would be available on network but **only** if you enable to share this `Public` folder in the

```
Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Network and Sharing Center\Advanced sharing settings
```

> As I found, however, no user/account owns that Public folder, though access can be given to the actual user accounts

Not really. Most operation systems has concept of ownership and permissions and windows one of them (begging from NT4). All resources that need to be accessible/shared should have an owner. If you make a right click on `c:\Users\Public` then go to "Properties->Security" you will find that this folder owned by group "Administrators" and permissions assigned to groups AFAIK "Owners,System,Services,Batch,Interactive" that makes this folder shared across user's accounts as well on the network but only if you enabled access in "advanced sharing settings" and enabled Private/Work network profile.

> Does this mean that microsoft's terminology "network discovery", and whatever functionality is encompassed by that term, only applies to the Public folder?

No. Basically "network discovery" simply either enable firewall to restrict access to shared folders (including Public folder) or it open ports in firewall that allows windows share(s) (to be discovered by others) as well "network discovery" enable scanning network for master browser who holds list of other computers available on a network.

"network discovery" by default disabled for "Public" network profile and enabled for "Private/Work" NETWORK profiles.

You correctly concluded in comments:

> each network profile applies to the whole computer, across all accounts. That is, those switches are not specific to the account that I'm logged into, even though some switches apply explicitly and specifically to the Public folder.

Concept of "Public" folder was added in attempt to simplify network sharing when no one user are logged into computer (kind of simple server) as well to allow simple sharing between user's accounts.

Comment: Based solely on the wording of your answer, it seems like we are again in violent agreement about the fact that no user/account owns the Public folder.  Rather, it is owned by a group.  You've also described more than once that the Public folder is mirrored to each user account.  To me, that implies that either a copy or a reference is provided to each user.  Is that actually the case, or does each user have direct access to the one authoritative copy of the Public folder tree?

Comment: "To me, that implies that either a copy or a reference is provided to each user." It isn't a copy of `c:\users\public` provided to each user, it is direct access to content of this folder. It is a shared folder available to all user's accounts on particular workstation. Giving ownership to a group is a common way to manage permissions in all operation systems. It universally gives access to a folder without need to know upfront names of new accounts. I used your word 'mirrored' to simplify understanding how it is works. Windows explorer simply using reference to "Public" in "Libraries".

Comment: I updated answer, let me know if there're still unclear details.

Comment: I don't recall using the word "mirror", but I think the answer is clear, with my comments and your answer regarding direct access to the Public folder by the various user accounts.  Thanks.